# Find table row count in scrollable div

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have table with 500 rows inside a scrollable div. How can I know how many rows are currently showing inside viewport of div.

My aim is to do partial update to the table after an update and make the rest of changes while scrolling.

Comment: Show us what you tried

Comment: I haven't tried. I don't know how to proceed

Comment: You could start by looking at the `.scrollTop()` of the `div` and the height of each row.

Comment: are you trying to do this with JS or jQuery?

Comment: You need to set an index in each row and use that to alter data in that row.

Answer (score 1):

You need to compare `scrollTop()` and `offset().top` to determine which rows are in your div area.

---

boundTop : where the"viewport" is starting
boundBottom : where the "viewport" is ending

```
var boundTop = div.scrollTop()
var boundBottom = div.scrollTop() + div.height()
```

trOffset : the position of each row

`var trOffset = $("table tr").offset().top`

---

On `scroll` event, check for each rows if `trOffset` is between `boundTop` and `boundBottom`, then you can add a class to the row (`.active`, for exemple), and finally you can update every `.active` row :

```
    $("table tr").each(function () {
        trOffset = $(this).offset().top;
        if ((trOffset > boundTop) && (trOffset < boundBottom)) {
            $(this).addClass("active");
            $("td", this).stop().animate({
                "padding": "4px 10px 4px 30px"
            }, "fast");

        } else {
            $(this).removeClass("active");
            $("td", this).stop().animate({
                "padding": "4px 30px 4px 10px"
            }, "fast");
        }
    });
```

---

> [Live exemple](https://jsfiddle.net/a666gm8g/)

Answer (score 1):

You would need to iterate each row which is visible.

Here is the fiddle- http://jsfiddle.net/j0up6z5y/

```
function isVisible( row, container ){

    var elementTop = $(row).offset().top,
        elementHeight = $(row).height(),
        containerTop = $(container).offset().top,
        containerHeight = $(container).height();

    return ((((elementTop - containerTop) + elementHeight) > 0) && ((elementTop - containerTop) < containerHeight));
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Once you have the index upon clicking in a row and then changing data you can modify the row on the page with the data returned from the AJAX call:

```
 function modifyCell(data) {
   var row = $("#tblResults tbody tr").eq(rowIndex);  //index set with the click
   var cell = $(row).children('td').eq(6);  // column to change
   $(cell).html(data);  //modify cell user sees.
 }
```